# An Object or Column Name is Empty

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="Visits_DataGrid" runat="server" BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" CellPadding="0" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" OnItemCommand="VisitsDataGrid_Click" OnSortCommand="Visits_DataGrid_SortCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
<ItemStyle ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
<HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" BackColor="#333333" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="" DataField="VisitID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Deadline Date" SortExpression="ORDER BY DeadlineDate">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# String.Format("{0:d}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DeadlineDate")) %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Assigned Staff Member" DataField="StaffName" SortExpression="ORDER BY StaffName"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="" DataField="StatusID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" SortExpression="ORDER BY StatusID"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Scheduled Date" SortExpression="ORDER BY ScheduledDate">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# String.Format("{0:d}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScheduledDate")) %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Created By" DataField="createdName" SortExpression="ORDER BY createdName"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:ButtonColumn Text="" HeaderText="" CommandName="Select" Visible="true"></asp:ButtonColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="pagingStyle" Mode="NumericPages" BackColor="#D3DEEF" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And the following sub w/ select query, which is inserting into this data grid:

```
Sub Visit_Load()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DAL As DAL.DataAccess = New DAL.DataAccess
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    strSQL = "SELECT TAV.VisitID, TAV.DeadlineDate, TU1.first_name + ' ' + TU1.last_name as StaffName, TAV.StatusID, TAVS.Status, TAV.ScheduledDate, TU2.first_name + ' ' + TU2.last_name as createdName " & _
        " from tblAgentVisit as TAV " & _
        " left join tblUser as TU1 on TAV.assignedStaff = TU1.user_id " & _
        " left join tblUser as TU2 on TAV.Created_user_id = TU2.user_id " & _
        " left join tblAgentVisitAgents as TAVA on TAV.VisitID = TAVA.VisitID " & _
        " left join tblAgentVisitStatus_L as TAVS on TAV.StatusID = TAVS.StatusID " & _
        " WHERE TAVA.AgtID = " & Utils.NumOrNull(agentID_Label.text) & _
        " AND TAVA.Prime = 1"
    strSQL &= " " & OrderGrid_Label.text    

    strSQL = Utils.replaceChars(strSQL)
    ds = DAL.ExecDataSet(strSQL, CommandType.Text)

    Visits_DataGrid.DataSource = ds
    Visits_DataGrid.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I continue to get the following error: `An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.` I've checked over and over, and can't find where I'm missing. Can anyone else see it?

Comment: There is a line break without `" & _`. What is `Utils.NumOrNull(agentID)`? In general: use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: It's a check we use in our system to pass in a numeric value only. If it would be null, it'd pass 0, which would still be valid.

Comment: use Profiler to grab what is being sent to the server and you will find your error pretty fast usually.  I would bet your sql statement is being truncated becasue you didn't define a length properly somewhere. BTW are you sure you wil never have a null in teh firstname last name fields as your code is not handling that.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain on that.

Comment: Try qualifying all columns, even in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I've updated the select query to qualify everything. The query works fine in the database, but still getting the error on my page. I know it shouldn't, but does the fact I'm not pulling my AgtID or Prime in my SELECT query mucking things up for the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, but haven't solved the problem yet.

When I try to select people's names using `TU1.first_name + ' ' + TU1.last_name as StaffName`, it doesn't like the added space and throws an error.

I can do `TU1.first_name + TU1.last_name as StaffName` and it works fine, but then the name formatting is all off. Suggestions on how to fix that?